# I am having problem on flutter after updating to latest flutter version

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-html

I have updated my flutter version and I am getting following errors. Other than that everything is working fine.

> The named parameter 'tagsList' isn't defined. The getter 'tags' isn't
> defined for the type 'Html'. The named parameter 'customRenders' isn't
> defined. The argument type 'EdgeInsets' can't be assigned to the
> parameter type 'HtmlPaddings?'. The argument type 'EdgeInsets' can't
> be assigned to the parameter type 'HtmlPaddings?'.

Here is my code:

```
Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(Dimensions.paddingSizeSmall, 0, Dimensions.paddingSizeDefault, Dimensions.paddingSizeSmall),
                            child: Html(data: widget.productModel!.details,
                              tagsList: Html.tags,
                              customRenders: {
                                tableMatcher(): tableRender(),
                              },
                              style: {
                              "table": Style(
                                  backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(0x50, 0xee, 0xee, 0xee),
                                ),
                                "tr": Style(
                                  border: const Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
                                ),
                                "th": Style(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                "td": Style(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                ),
```

[image: Problem Screenshot]

Can anyone please help me. I know this is the problem generated by flutter_html. But I am unable to find solution.

I tried all the forums and everyone I know. But I am having this problem after updating dependencies and flutter. So please anyone help me.

Comment: https://github.com/Sub6Resources/flutter_html/wiki/Migration-Guides

Comment: hi pskink thanks. But I am new on Flutter so couldn't find what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [official migration guide](https://github.com/Sub6Resources/flutter_html/wiki/Migration-Guides)

> **`customRender` has been changed to `extensions`,** and its API is now significantly different. `extensions` accepts a `List<Extension>`.

> **This parameter has been split into two different options:** `doNotRenderTheseTags` and `onlyRenderTheseTags`. All supported tags are allowed by default, including tags supported by extensions. This allows you to either restrict certain tags from rendering (say you don't want any images rendered), or allow only a certain subset of tags to render (say you only want h1-h6 and p tags to be rendered). Both `doNotRenderTheseTags` and `onlyRenderTheseTags` take a Set.

> If you were using the `style` parameter in your Html widget, there are some minor changes to the API that introduce some huge possibilites.

Follow this guide and everything will be correctly working again.

If this doesn't help, please let me know and I'll provide more support to you.
Happy coding!

***EDIT***

Please, **update your `flutter_html` version to `Beta 3` and migrate your code following the official migration guide I linked above**. The code in the document is the same you posted in your question. Update your code using the Migration Guide and let me know if this solves your problems

Comment: I read the whole article but still cant solve please help me.

Comment: What's wrong ? Still having the same errors ? Can you add errors in your question ?

Comment: Or can you add your most recent code after following the guide ? Can you also add your pubspec.yaml ? @Punkkk

Comment: Yes sure I am using the following dependencies:

Comment: Can you please add your pubspec.yaml and your updated code in your question ? @Punkkk

Comment: All details are written in the document please check the end. Thank You https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vS0jDtAFpG72y1aW9KOsOAaaH63AnTcqDIf8OBhchSTLzKY_LN4meKFYaFNHwh8QQ8K8L0aYuPlhSjl/pub

Comment: Sorry didn't find the link before. Try updating your flutter_html version. Beta 2 is out

Comment: I am having this problem after I updated the flutter_html. I have edited my questions. You can now see all my errors above. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `EdgeInsets.all(8)` to `HtmlPaddings.all(8)`. Unfortunately that is not documented in the migration guide, I just found it out from the source code. Alternatively they provide an extension `.htmlPadding` on `EdgeInsets`, so you could also write `const EdgeInsets.all(4).htmlPadding`.

Seems like there is still some work to do until `flutter_html` version 3 is ready to be released...

Your other two issues are mentioned in the migration guide. For getting tables to work you need to remove the `customRender` stuff and instead write
`extensions: const [TableHtmlExtension()]`. You also need to add a dependency on `flutter_html_table` in `pubspec.yaml` (by calling `flutter pub add flutter_html_table`)

Regarding the `tagsList` parameter I didn't understand what you want to achieve, maybe you can just remove that line?
So it should be (untested):

```
  Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(Dimensions.paddingSizeSmall, 0, Dimensions.paddingSizeDefault, Dimensions.paddingSizeSmall),
    child: Html(data: widget.productModel!.details,
      extensions: const [TableHtmlExtension()],
      style: {
      "table": Style(
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(0x50, 0xee, 0xee, 0xee),
        ),
        "tr": Style(
          border: const Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
        ),
        "th": Style(
          padding: const HtmlPaddings.all(6),
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        ),
        "td": Style(
          padding: const HtmlPaddings.all(6),
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        ),
```